Credo / AFJ : Error sending message to https://----mediator-url---- Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
I am trying to run the following code to initialize a Credo / Aries Framework Javascript agent in React Native iOS (Simulator as well as iPhone Device) environment in an Expo ^50 version :
import {
  Agent,
  ConnectionEventTypes,
  ConnectionsModule,
  ConsoleLogger,
  DidExchangeState,
  LogLevel,
  MediationRecipientModule,
  MediatorPickupStrategy,
  KeyDerivationMethod,
  HttpOutboundTransport,
  WsOutboundTransport,
  InitConfig,
} from "@credo-ts/core"
import { agentDependencies } from "@credo-ts/react-native"
import { AskarModule } from "@credo-ts/askar"
import { ariesAskar } from "@hyperledger/aries-askar-react-native"

const mediatorInvitationUrl = https://url...

const config: InitConfig = {
  label: "standalone-agent-11",
  walletConfig: {
    id: "standalone-agent-11",
    key: "00000000001000000000000000000011",
    keyDerivationMethod: KeyDerivationMethod.Argon2IMod,
  },
  logger: new ConsoleLogger(LogLevel.trace),
  // autoUpdateStorageOnStartup: true,
}

const agent = new Agent({
  config,
  modules: {
    askar: new AskarModule({ ariesAskar }),
    connections: new ConnectionsModule({ autoAcceptConnections: true }),
    mediationRecipient: new MediationRecipientModule({
      mediatorInvitationUrl,
      mediatorPickupStrategy: MediatorPickupStrategy.Implicit,
    }),
  },
  dependencies: agentDependencies,
})

agent.registerOutboundTransport(new WsOutboundTransport())
agent.registerOutboundTransport(new HttpOutboundTransport())

export const ScreenName = () => {

 useEffect(() => {
     agent
       .initialize()
       .then((_) => console.log("Agent initialized!"))
       .catch((err) => console.log("Agent not initialized:", err))
   }, [])


return <View>
<Text>Hi</Text>
<View>


}

If i remove this snippet below, the code works perfectly fine and logs out Agent initialized! as expected:
  mediationRecipient: new MediationRecipientModule({
      mediatorInvitationUrl,
      mediatorPickupStrategy: MediatorPickupStrategy.Implicit,
    }),


But when I keep that snippet, I get the following error when I run yarn ios or yarn ios --device:
 INFO  INFO: Creating agent with config {
  "agentConfig": {
    "label": "standalone-agent-11",
    "walletConfig": {
      "id": "standalone-agent-11",
      "key": "[*****]",
      "keyDerivationMethod": "ARGON2I_MOD",
      "storage": {}
    },
    "logger": 1,
    "agentDependencies": true
  }
}
 INFO  INFO: Initializing wallet 'standalone-agent-11' {
  "id": "standalone-agent-11",
  "key": "[*****]",
  "keyDerivationMethod": "ARGON2I_MOD",
  "storage": {}
}
 LOG  Hermes: true
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Wallet 'standalone-agent-11' not found
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Creating wallet 'standalone-agent-11
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Successfully created wallet 'standalone-agent-11'
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Setting current agent storage version to 0.5
 LOG  TRACE: Storage upgrade record does not exist yet. Creating.
 INFO  INFO: Agent storage is up to date.
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Starting WS outbound transport
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Starting HTTP outbound transport
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Provision mediation with invitation {
  "mediatorInvitationUrl": "https://url..."
}
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Mediation connection does not exist, creating connection
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Routing created {
  "endpoints": [
    "didcomm:transport/queue"
  ],
  "routingKeys": [],
  "recipientKey": {
    "keyType": "ed25519",
    "publicKeyBase58": "---xyz---"
  }
}
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Searching for an existing connection for out-of-band invitation. { .... }
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Retrieved 0 connections for invitation did did:peer:2.V....
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Out of band message contains handshake protocols.
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Connection does not exist or reuse is disabled. Creating a new connection.
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Create message https://didcomm.org/didexchange/1.1/request start { .... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: creating did peer
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Updating state { ... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Create message https://didcomm.org/didexchange/1.1/request end { .... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Send outbound message { ... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Retrieving services for connection 'id---id---id' (Aries Framework JavaScript Mediator) { ... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Resolving services from out-of-band record --id--.
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Retrieved 2 services for message to connection '--id--'(Aries Framework JavaScript Mediator)' {
  "hasQueueService": false
}

 DEBUG  DEBUG: resolving didUrl did:peer:1z....
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to service: { 

  "messageId": "--id--",
  "service": {
    "id": "#inline-0",
    "recipientKeys": "omitted...",
    "routingKeys": "omitted...",
    "serviceEndpoint": "https://url..."
  }
}

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Pack outbound message https://didcomm.org/didexchange/1.1/request
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to endpoint 'https://url...' { ... }

ERROR: Error sending message to http://--url--:3001: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined {
  "error": {
    "name": "TypeError",
    "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined\n    at ?anon_0_ (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:438453:107)\n    at next (native)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6856:26)\n    at _next (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6875:29)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6880:14)\n    at tryCallTwo (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:61:9)\n    at doResolve (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:216:25)\n    at Promise (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:82:14)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6872:25)\n    at apply (native)\n    at sendMessage (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:438527:36)\n    at ?anon_0_ (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:439741:42)\n    at next (native)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6856:26)\n    at _next (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6875:29)\n    at tryCallOne (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)\n    at anonymous (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39976:26)\n    at _callTimer (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39855:17)\n    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39900:17)\n    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:40106:44)\n    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8664:48)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8437:45)\n    at __guard (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8636:15)\n    at flushedQueue (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8436:21)",
    "message": "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined"
  },
  "message": "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined",
  "body": {
    "protected": "---",
    "ciphertext": "---",
    "iv": "---",
    "tag": "---"
  },
  "didCommMimeType": "application/didcomm-envelope-enc"
}
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to service with id #inline-0 failed with the following error: {
  "message": "Error sending message to http://--url---:3001: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined",
  "error": {
    "name": "CredoError",
    "message": "Error sending message to http://--url--:3001: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined",
    "stack": "CredoError: Error sending message to https://--url--: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined\n    at ?anon_0_ (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:438518:89)\n    at next (native)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6856:26)\n    at _next (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6875:29)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6880:14)\n    at tryCallTwo (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:61:9)\n    at doResolve (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:216:25)\n    at Promise (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:82:14)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6872:25)\n    at apply (native)\n    at sendMessage (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:438527:36)\n    at ?anon_0_ (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:439741:42)\n    at next (native)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6856:26)\n    at _next (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6875:29)\n    at tryCallOne (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)\n    at anonymous (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39976:26)\n    at _callTimer (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39855:17)\n    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39900:17)\n    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:40106:44)\n    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8664:48)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8437:45)\n    at __guard (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8636:15)\n    at flushedQueue (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8436:21)",
    "cause": {
      "name": "TypeError",
      "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined\n    at ?anon_0_ (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:438453:107)\n    at next (native)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6856:26)\n    at _next (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6875:29)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6880:14)\n    at tryCallTwo (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:61:9)\n    at doResolve (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:216:25)\n    at Promise (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:82:14)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6872:25)\n    at apply (native)\n    at sendMessage (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:438527:36)\n    at ?anon_0_ (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:439741:42)\n    at next (native)\n    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6856:26)\n    at _next (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:6875:29)\n    at tryCallOne (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)\n    at anonymous (/Users/distiller/react-native/packages/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39976:26)\n    at _callTimer (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39855:17)\n    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:39900:17)\n    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:40106:44)\n    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8664:48)\n    at anonymous (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8437:45)\n    at __guard (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8636:15)\n    at flushedQueue (http://--url--:8081/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true&transform.engine=hermes&transform.bytecode=true&transform.routerRoot=app:8436:21)",
      "message": "Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined"
    }
  }
}

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to service: { ... }
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Pack outbound message https://didcomm.org/didexchange/1.1/request
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to endpoint 'ws://---url---' over WebSocket transport. { ... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Connecting to WebSocket ws://--url--
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Successfully connected to WebSocket ws://--url--
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Mediation invitation processed { ... }

 LOG  TRACE: WebSocket message event received. { ... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Payload received from mediator: { ... }

/////////// SOME MORE LOGS IN BETWEEN ////////////

 DEBUG  DEBUG: resolving didUrl did:peer:1z...
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to endpoint 'https://--url--' { ... }

 ERROR  ERROR: Error sending message to https://--url--: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined {
  "error": {
    "name": "TypeError",
    "stack": "TypeError: .... SAME LOGS AS ABOVE
    }
}

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to service with id #inline-0 failed with the following error: {
  "message": "Error sending message to https://--url--: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined",
  "error": {
    "name": "CredoError",
    "message": "Error sending message to https:/--url--: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined",
    "stack": "CredoError: Error sending message to https://--url--: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined\n ----- SAME LOGS AS ABOVE -----



///// SOME MORE LOGS IN BETWEEN /////

 DEBUG  DEBUG: Sending outbound message to endpoint 'ws://--url--' over WebSocket transport. { ... }

 DEBUG  DEBUG: WebSocket closing to ws://:3001
 LOG  Agent not initialized: [TimeoutError: Timeout has occurred]



Note : I believe this has something to do with iOS/Xcode Configurations on network and other ends, because it seems to work on bare react native (Not Expo) apps but ONLY ON ANDROID VERSION.

Can you share the URL of the mediator used? It seems that the response from the mediator is not okay, since you are able to send the message but not to read the response associated.
